# using a redirect to launch an app and still stay in same page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, redirect

I have written a website that uses bankid authentication, I don't know how common this is outside of sweden, but basically it is either an app in the mobile phone, or a local software in windows. to launch the application in windows a redirect needs to be made that looks like this:

```
if (startLocalApp)
            {
                Response.Redirect("bankid:///?autostarttoken=" + AuthResp.AuthenticateResponse1.AutoStartToken + "&redirect=" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
            }
```

the problem with this though is that the redirect of the software does not work the way I need it to work since the redirect it does opens a new tab with the web page I need to get back to in a new tab, and the session variable is all messed up. so what I need to do is the opposite, launch the app in a new tab, and let it close the tab when it's done, since I have all references needed before I've launched the app it does not need to be executed in the same browser window even.

so how to make the redirect in another tab, and is it possible to keep executing code after the redirect? if not, I need to make a post back to continue execution of the code-behind.

edit:
I've tried one solution, it feels like I'm getting closer but I'm not quite there yet.
front-end:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function StartBankIdApp(){
        var _url = 'bankid:///?autostarttoken=<%= (AuthResp == null || AuthResp.AuthenticateResponse1 == null) ? "null" : AuthResp.AuthenticateResponse1.AutoStartToken %>&redirect=null';
        var $irWin = window.open(_url, '_blank');
        if ($irWin != null) {
            $irWin.close();
        }
    }
</script>
```

code-behind:

```
if (startLocalApp)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), StartBankIdApp", "StartBankIdApp()", true);
}
```

the app is not launched, i.e the window it should open does not open.
did I do something wrong?

Comment: I can add that all this is inside a .ascx user control, not an .aspx website

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to use "URL scheme" to launch an app. And that you want that the app should be triggered in a new tab (or window).

This can be achieved through javascript. To open any link in new tab we can use window.open and set target attribute as _blank. Here is a sample code

```
var _url = 'app:MyApp?queryString=somestring';
var $irWin = window.open(_url, '_blank');
if ($irWin != null) {
   $irWin.close();
}
```

What I've done here is that after launching the app I've closed the new tab (or window).

The javaScript code would continue to run (that is it will not wait for the app to complete the process).

Comment: I shall try this out! any tips on how to call the javascript from code behind where the redirect is now?

Comment: you can use ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript method from code behind

Comment: can you check my edit if I wrote the javascript part correctly? the code-behind works like it should, I don't know if the javascript is even executed or if it doesn't work.